# No carga imagen cuando hago Build en Next js 12

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, nextjs

Estoy con un proyecto en next js 12, donde subo imagenes al backend para que este lo guarde en el servidor en la carpeta public, para despues renderizarlo en el cliente, esto funciona perfectamente en entorno de desarrollo pero cuando hago un build para construir la aplicacion y ejecuto npm run start y guardo imagenes desde el cliente esta no reconoce las imagenes en el lado del cliente, me responde con un

http://localhost:3000/_next/image?url=%2Fuploads%2F1699470211973_132412260_4070328449648831_511247340400065990_n.jpg&w=384&q=75 400 (Bad Request)

del lado del servidor en la consola obtengo un:
The requested resource isn't a valid image for /uploads/1699544051443.png received text/html; charset=utf-8

adjunto codigo de como guardo las imagenes en el backend.

```
const form = new multiparty.Form();
        
          form.parse(req, async (err, fields, files) => {
            if (err) {
              res.status(500).json({ error: "Error al cargar la imagen" });
              return;
            }
        
            console.log(err);
        
            const { photo } = files; // Accede al archivo subido
            const data = fields.data ? JSON.parse(fields.data[0]) : {};
        
            // if (!photo || !photo[0]) {
            //     res.status(400).json({ error: 'Archivo no encontrado en la solicitud' });
            //     return;
            // }
        
            if (photo !== undefined) {
              const oldPath = photo[0].path;
              let newFile = photo[0].originalFilename.split(".");
              newFile = newFile[1];
              const newPath = path.join(
                process.cwd(),
                "public/uploads",
                `${Date.now()}.${newFile}`
              );
              let filePath = newPath.replace(/\\/g, "/");
              filePath = filePath.split("/");
              filePath = "/" + filePath[8] + "/" + filePath[9];
              fs.rename(oldPath, newPath, async (err) => {
                if (err) {
                  console.error(err);
                  res.status(500).json({ error: "Error al mover el archivo" });
                  return;
                }
        
                const { question, answers, category } = data;
        
                try {
                  try {
                    let [category_id] = await connection.query(
                      `SELECT id FROM category WHERE NAME = '${category}'`
                    );
        
                    category_id = category_id[0].id;
        
                    await connection.query(`INSERT INTO 
                                    preguntas(question, url_image, category_id, create_by) 
                                    VALUES ('${question}','${filePath}', ${category_id}, ${id})`);
        
                    let [question_id] = await connection.query(
                      `SELECT id FROM preguntas WHERE question = '${question}'`
                    );
        
                    question_id = question_id[0].id;
        
                    answers.forEach(async (e) => {
                      await connection.query(`INSERT INTO 
                                        respuestas(answer, r_id, create_by) 
                                        VALUES ('${e.answer}', ${question_id}, ${id})`);
        
                      let answer_id = await connection.query(
                        `SELECT id FROM respuestas WHERE answer = '${e.answer}'`
                      );
                      answer_id = answer_id[0][0].id;
        
                      await connection.query(`
                                        INSERT INTO answerquestion(pid, rid) 
                                        VALUES (${question_id},${answer_id})`);
                    });
                    return res.status(200).json("success");
                  } catch (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    return res.status(501).json("error");
                  }
                } catch (error) {
                  console.error(error);
                  return res.status(501).json("error");
                }
              });
            } else {
              const { question, answers, category } = data;
        
              try {
                try {
                  let [category_id] = await connection.query(
                    `SELECT id FROM category WHERE NAME = '${category}'`
                  );
        
                  category_id = category_id[0].id;
        
                  await connection.query(`INSERT INTO 
                                    preguntas(question, category_id, create_by) 
                                    VALUES ('${question}', ${category_id}, ${id})`);
        
                  let [question_id] = await connection.query(
                    `SELECT id FROM preguntas WHERE question = '${question}'`
                  );
        
                  question_id = question_id[0].id;
        
                  answers.forEach(async (e) => {
                    await connection.query(`INSERT INTO 
                                        respuestas(answer, r_id, create_by) 
                                        VALUES ('${e.answer}', ${question_id}, ${id})`);
        
                    let answer_id = await connection.query(
                      `SELECT id FROM respuestas WHERE answer = '${e.answer}'`
                    );
                    answer_id = answer_id[0][0].id;
        
                    await connection.query(`
                                        INSERT INTO answerquestion(pid, rid) 
                                        VALUES (${question_id},${answer_id})`);
                  });
                  return res.status(200).json("success");
                } catch (error) {
                  console.log(error);
                  return res.status(501).json("error");
                }
              } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
                return res.status(501).json("error");
              }
            }
          });
```

De esta manera estoy renderizando la imagen

```
{
                item.url_image !== null &&
                item.url_image.length > 0 ? (
                  <Image
                    src={item.url_image}
                    width={300}
                    height={150}
                    alt="question image"
                    onClick={() => {
                      setImage(item.url_image);
                      setViewImage(!viewImage);
                    }}
                  />
                ) : (
                  ""
                )}
```

en la base de datos guardo la ruta de la imagen para luego usarla en la etiqueta  pero esta no me la renderiza correctamente

Comment: Falta código de la ruta de la API y también del componente en el cliente que renderiza la imagen. Recuerda que las imágenes que se guardan localmente deben se deben acceder por medio de un `URL RELATIVO` si estás usando el `url absoluto` next.js te va a mostrar ese error.

Comment: La cosa es que funciona muy bien en desarrollo pero en produccion deja funcionar correctamente, solo me deja de mostrar las imagenes. y la ruta que le voy pasando a la etiqueta image es la que me muestra en el error del lado del servidor

Comment: En actualizacion al problema, cuando vuelvo a construir la aplicacion, esta si me renderiza las imagenes

Comment: cuál es el valor del url de la imagen `item.url_image` en tu build de producción si le haces `console.log`?

Comment: @jonoise '/uploads/1699553357338.png' eso sale del console.log